# How to set a base url in a springboot graphql app

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

How can we set a base url in springboot graphql-server app .
By default the `graphiql` api-console opens on http://localhost:8080/graphiql

Trying to access http://localhost:8080 through postman with a post -query as below :

```
{
    bookings {
        name
    }
}
```

gives an error saying :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1549913598497,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/"
}
```

1. Q1 what should be the path to the server i should be using to invoke it.
2. Q2 is there a way to provide a custom base path something loke http://localhost:8080/service/api/query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually the server path for graphql endpoints is at `http://localhost:8080/graphql`. If not just inspect the network tab on your browser when you run a query on your GraphiQL interface, it will run the query on the api endpoint.
2. In order to change the base path you would need to change `application.properties` into something like:

```
    graphql.servlet.mapping: /service/api/query

    graphiql.mapping: /graphiql
    graphiql.endpoint: /service/api/query
```

Comment: @TarunPatel you should then specify the version on your question. And the answer for the first question should be correct.

Comment: :update .. my bad.. had some issues on jars/version  conflicts across graphql and speingboot which was causing the problem for me. Have marked tyour answer as correct . thanks for the help

Comment: as for me 
`graphql.url = /test` in **application.properties** worked, so the url will be like: http://localhost:8080/test.
`graphql-java-spring-boot-starter-webmvc, version 2019-06-24T11-47-27-31ab4f9`

Comment: This has been changed to `spring.graphql.path=`  https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-M2/reference/html/

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring Boot Property file you can change the base url like below:

```
spring.graphql.path=/service/api/query
```

Example:
When I changed the base url like below.:

```
spring.graphql.path=/api/projects/graphql
```

It reflected like below in console:

*2022-11-05 08:58:14.964  INFO 17336 --- [           main] s.b.a.g.s.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration : GraphQL endpoint HTTP POST /api/projects/graphql*

More can be found at below official document:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

add `graphql.url = /test`

in application.properties