# How to modify graphql endpoint URL in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I created a simple graphql implementation in springboot.

Now, to fetch APIs I have to use URL `http://localhost:XXXX/graphql` but I want to fetch it on `http://localhost:XXXX/api/graphql`. I want to append `api/` before it. How to do it?

I tried all online solutions to write code in application.ymls like

Use url

```
**graphiql:
  url: /api/graphql
  enabled: true
```

OR modify endpoint

```
graphiql:
    endpoint:
      graphql: /api/graphql
    enabled: true**
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change spring boot 2.0 context-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192878/change-spring-boot-2-0-context-path)

Comment: @ChinHuang It does tell a way to change path, but somehow things are getting applicable in case of graphql. My issue is endpoints are not getting applied, still APIs are exposed on URL/graphql not URL/api/graphql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671034/6124657